# Make duplicates real produces too many objects

Tags: mesh, bezier-curves

I'm new to Blender (using version 2.74); I was looking for a way to position several Suzannes in a circle and came across [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/510/how-can-i-duplicate-a-mesh-along-a-curve) which has an answer based on this [Blender wiki page](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Objects/Duplication/DupliFrames).

I followed it (several times from scratch, actually), trying to position 6 Suzannes in a circle. It works for me up to the point when I do <kbd>Ctr</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to *make duplicates real*. When I do this, my 6 Suzannes are still in a circle but the *Outliner* shows there are now 100 Suzannes in the scene; which is actually true - 94 Suzannes are hidden under one of the 6 other ones.

The number 100 happens to coincide with the default setting of *Path Animation -> Frames*; I made sure to change that to 6 as mentioned [in the tutorial](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Objects/Duplication/DupliFrames). Which doesn't fix it.

Why does the number of Suzannes go from 6 up to 100 when I *make duplicates real*? Is there a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: Are the start and end values set correctly in *Duplication > Frames*?

Comment: blender.stackexchange suggested [this question](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7165/dupliframes-creating-too-few-objects) which appears to be the same problem. Investigating now

Comment: @gandalf3 Both the curve and the object have the `Duplication->Frame` setting, the wiki page says to change it for the curve while stackexchange mentions that it should be changed for the object rather than the curve. I do not understand it fully, though

Comment: *Duplication > Frames* It should be enabled on the object.

Comment: yes, thank you, I did that and it helped. My question happened to be the duplicate of [this one](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7165/dupliframes-creating-too-few-objects), sorry. I could find that via google, it was suggested my stackexchange when I typed up my own question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because there were always 100 Suzannes.

Dupliframes will always create the same number of duplicates, even if the object is not moving. By default it's set to duplicate frames 1-100. If you only want to duplicate frames 1-6, then change the start and end values to match the desired range:

[image]